# How to change value of a specific element in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans

So here I have an array of numbers and I want to change the value of a specific index only.

```
ArrayList <Integer> numbers = new ArrayList <> ();
numbers.add(5);
numbers.add(10);
numbers.add(20);
```

I was trying to do something like
`userNumbers.get(1 (* 3));` where `1` should be the index and I'd multiply  the value in that index by 3 therefore will result as `30` since `10` is the 1st index. Tried searching up but no luck for me!

Comment: You need to do a `get` and a `set`, `numbers.set(1, numbers.get(1) * 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think it is because "Integer" is an immutable class, which means you cannot change the value of an immutable object with its member method.

If you put Integer, Long , Float ,Double, Boolean, Short, Byte, Character, String and other immutable classes in the list, you cannot change the value instantly.

But if you put customized objects in the list , you can change the value.

Demo code:

```
public class RRR {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Hi> hiList = new ArrayList <> ();
        Hi hi1 = new Hi("one");
        Hi hi2 = new Hi("two");
        Hi hi3 = new Hi("three");
        hiList.add(hi1);
        hiList.add(hi2);
        hiList.add(hi3);
        Hi hix = hiList.get(0);
        hix.setName("haha");
        System.out.println(hiList.get(0).getName());    // changed from "one" to "haha"
    }


}

class Hi {
    public Hi(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

See? The class Hi is not Immutable , you can change this value with "setName"

Back to the question, change this Integer object , you can:

1. Copy the new value and origin values to a new list, if your list is not too large(not good).
2. Delete the old element, then set the new value to the right index.(should consider thread safe problem)

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the Java documentation whenever possible. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-) in particular.

```
numbers.set(1, numbers.get(1) * 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a static method to make the changes, you could possibly add this method to the ArrayList class as well. This will multiply the element by 3 as you said you wanted in your post:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(10);
    numbers.add(20);

    System.out.println(numbers.get(2)); //before

    changeList(numbers, 2);

    System.out.println(numbers.get(2)); //After!
}

//This method will take in the list, and the element number
static void changeList(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList, int elementNum) {
    int temp = arrayList.get(elementNum);
    arrayList.remove(elementNum); //remove it

    int newValue = temp * 3; //do anything you want here to the data
    arrayList.add(elementNum, newValue); //place the value back in the arrayList
}
```